# What causes an application on one PC to be able to open OneDrive "files" but not on another PC?

Tags: windows-10, symbolic-link, onedrive

I have an application that uses files I have sync'd with OneDrive.

On machine A, when I launch this application (Blender 4.0, as it happens) and use the application's "File->Open" menu to open a file, a File Explorer progress dialog pops up indicating that OneDrive is retrieving the file from the cloud and when the retrieval is complete the file opens as normal.

On machine B, using the same process with the same OneDrive account to open the same file produces a "file format not recognized" error. (My guess is that Blender is picking up a file that is actually a shortcut/link, which is of course not a file format it recognizes).

On both machines if I browse to the file in File Explorer and double-click on the not-yet-downloaded file in OneDrive, it downloads the file and launches the application just fine. Again, this works the same on both machines.

I have even used the OneDrive "Free Up Space" option to ensure that the file in question is NOT on my hard drive, yet Machine A opens it without any trouble. Machine B can open files that are set to "Keep on this Device" or are already downloaded, naturally, but not if they're "in the cloud" (are they symlinks?).

I'm also investigating application specific settings that might be causing this, but I really don't think so (I've reinstalled many times in both locations, with stock settings; this has also been true since Blender 3.0). I suspect there is something about the way that Windows is presenting the file to Blender that is making it work in one case, but not in the other case.

The usual details:
Both machines are running the latest patches of Windows 10 64bit.
Both use AMD processors (an FX and a Ryzen 9).
Both are using SSDs.

Any ideas what might be causing this behavior? Could it be a permissions thing? Same Microsoft account on both machines...

Comment: I doubt it's a permissions thing. What is blender version on the broken PC B? Is it the EXACT same or higher as PC A? Windows has an odd/empty file when the file isn't downloaded from OneDrive that may be confusing blender as it's likely not knowledgeable about cloud storage. On PC B(roken) you could tell OneDrive to download all your files so it isn't downloading on the file as you said double-clicking from File Explorer works fine. That kind of implies it's a blender/OneDrive combo oddity at fault. There is a way to wipe OneDrive config on a PC to start fresh

Comment: Yes, they are EXACTLY the same version of Blender. I agree, the "empty-ish" file that OneDrive uses for remote files is almost certainly confusing Blender. I think it's just a regular symlink, but it's hard to tell. The weird thing is (again) it works on one Windows machine, but not the other. I seem to remember there being some config related to symlinks... but that might be a red herring. I can "keep on this device" for the whole directory but it's A LOT of files, and it kinda defeats the benefit of only downloading what I need. Double-clicking in FE is also a reasonable workaround.

Comment: Maybe how File Explorer 'View' is setup (icons [Thumbnails] or Preview Pane) on PC A is downloading the files (not Blender) for you whereas the Explorer View on PC (B)roken isn't setup that way. Googling Blender OneDrive seems to imply this is a quirk of their app, we can't fix Blender for you. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107331/how-can-i-access-onedrive-from-within-blender https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/87621 https://devtalk.blender.org/t/adding-explicit-cloud-drive-onedrive-icloud-drive-support/19076